# Firebase admin Java client at scale

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Did anyone try to use firebase-admin with Java at big scale?

I'm working on an IoT project with Firebase and need a way to store thousands of values to Firebase per second. I've implemented firebase-admin library into my backend application but if I try to stress test it (with like few thousand requests per second), client starts to lag.

I've been reading client internals and I can see that it's using queue that holds Firebase queries. There is one thread in the executor (RevivingScheduledExecutor) that pulls queries from queue and sends them via web socket to Firebase database. The problem is if I do it at scale, queue stars to grow 'cause client is not able to send so many queries, so queries start to lag for a second, a few, then minutes... until memory leaks out (too many queries get stuck and unprocessed inside queue).

Anybody faced a problem? How do I scale it?

Thanks alot in advance, I've been trying to fix this for days and days.

Comment: Java RTDB client is really a port of the the Android client. So it really operates as a single app would. Python and Go implementations of the RTDB client can handle large volumes better, since they are completely stateless and uses the RTDB REST API underneath (caveat is that they don't support real time listeners). If you must use the Java implementation, running multiple FirebaseApp/FirebaseDatabase instances, and distributing the load across them is probably your best option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with custom Java REST client than or multiple FirebaseApps.